# Feature selection for multilabel classification (scikit-learn)

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection, chi-squared

I'm trying to do a feature selection by chi-square method in scikit-learn (sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest). When I'm trying to apply this to a multilabel problem, I get this warning:

`UserWarning: Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering.There are probably duplicate features, or you used a classification score for a regression task.
  warn("Duplicate scores. Result may depend on feature ordering."`

Why is it appearning and how to properly apply feature selection is this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code warns you that arbitrary tie-breaking may need to be performed because some features have exactly the same score.

That said, feature selection does not actually work for multilabel out of the box; the best you can currently do is tie feature selection and a classifier together in a pipeline, then feed that to a multilabel meta-estimator. Example (untested):

```
clf = Pipeline([('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
                ('svm', LinearSVC())])
multi_clf = OneVsRestClassifier(clf)
```

(This warning is, I believe, issued even when the tied features aren't actually the k'th and (k+1)'th, I think. It can usually be ignored safely.)

Comment: The warning still appears in this case (when feature selection is in the pipeline)

Comment: @lizarisk: I wasn't suggesting that as a fix for the warning, but as a way to do feature selection in the multilabel case. I'm not completely sure if it's the only way to do this; neither I, nor any core dev, ever considered this combination, I think.

Comment: What do you mean by "feature selection does work for multilabel out of the box"? Since it doesn't crash, what is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is a bit old but the following is working for me:

```
clf = Pipeline([('chi2', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
            ('lasso', OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))])
```

Comment: Wouldn't this perform feature selection on the entire training dataset at once rather than separately for each base classifier? I would expect that compared to the accepted answer, you could get bad performance for some labels.