# multilabel feature selection

Tags: python, feature-selection, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to find examples of implementing `multi-label` feature selection through using any of problem transformation methods in `python`, but unfortunately I couldn't found a clear example.

Comment: Hello! Does this and linked questions help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037450/multi-label-feature-selection-using-sklearn

Comment: I have been throng this example before, used different method and they heven't used any of problems transformation method. Sorry not this what  I'm looking for.