# Issue with SelectKBest() when using with MultiOutputRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am not able to use SelectKBest for feature selection in a Pipeline concluding with MultiOutputRegressor (see below, where pipe1 works fine, but pipe2 leads to an error -- given below). It seems SelectKBest is not able to handle y with multiple columns. Is this a known limitation?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,10))
y = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,2))

pipe1 = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False)), \
                     ('regr', MultiOutputRegressor(Ridge()))])

pipe1.fit(X, y)

pipe2 = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False)), \
                 ('kbst', SelectKBest(f_regression, k=5)), \
                     ('regr', MultiOutputRegressor(Ridge()))])

pipe2.fit(X, y)
```

Here is the error message:

```
 ValueError
 ---> 17 pipe2.fit(X, y) [...] /home/ecm/.conda/envs/mlpolar/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py
 in column_or_1d(y, warn)
     845     raise ValueError(
     846         "y should be a 1d array, "
 --> 847         "got an array of shape {} instead.".format(shape))
     848 
     849 
 
 ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (100, 2) instead.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16421186/1453508) help?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thanks @DavidM. Will write a post with the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the suggested post indicated in the comments, here is how to fix the
problem:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

X = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,10))
y = np.random.normal(0,1,(100,2))

pipe_in = Pipeline([('kbst', SelectKBest(f_regression, k=5)), \
                     ('regr', Ridge())])
pipe2 = Pipeline([('poly', PolynomialFeatures(2, include_bias=False)), \
                     ('pipe', MultiOutputRegressor(pipe_in))])

pipe2.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Just be aware that in this way each target variable may select a different subset of features.